# CefSharp download file permissions

Tags: c#, download, cefsharp

I am new to CefSharp and trying to get it to handle downloads.  I have implemented IDownloadHandler and it's downloading just how I want to a temp directory.  However, after download I try to do more with the file, but it seems it's downloaded with no permissions whatsoever, so it gives me access denied when I try to do anything with it (in this case unpack the zip file).

I can go view the file through File Explorer and I get the message in the security tab 'No groups or users have permission to access this object...'.  If I add myself as a user it's fine, but without doing that I can't do anything with the file.

So how do you download something and make it accessible to use?

Here is my download handler class:

```
class CefDownloadHandler : IDownloadHandler
{
    public void OnBeforeDownload(IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem, IBeforeDownloadCallback callback)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Before Download");

        callback.Continue(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), downloadItem.SuggestedFileName), false);
    }

    public void OnDownloadUpdated(IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem, IDownloadItemCallback callback)
    {
        if (downloadItem.IsComplete)
        {
            new FileInfo(downloadItem.FullPath).SetAccessControl(new System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity())
            CoreApp.StartContentLoad(downloadItem.FullPath, downloadItem.Url);
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

This seems to be related to the location after more testing.  I was originally saving to the temp directory using Path.GetTempPath() and having this issue.  Just to test I modifed to use a folder under %appdata% and it saves with normal permissions and works.  I have access and permissions to the temp folder so I'm not sure why but it seems to be related to that...

Comment: What version are you using? Does the problem reproduce if you apply your `DownloadHandler` to https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/tree/cefsharp/69 (branch using the latest `-pre` release).
I'm not seeing any problems, nor have I had other reports of problems.

Comment: Could be one of those cases you need an `app.manifest` with `compatibility` entries, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms/app.manifest#L43

Comment: I'm using version 57 and unfortunately I have to do so.  The program is an add-in to another program that uses CEF 57 so I have to align with that...

Comment: I don't think I can do a manifest when it's an add-in to another program can I?  Sorry I should have mentioned that part at first.  However, I am running this as a standalone application for testing the base system but in final form it will have to be embedded in the other app that I don't have control of...

Answer (score 0):

you should not save directly on ApplicationData folder, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54011482/357588).